# BusacrV en hojas diferentes usando Macros

Tags: vba

Alguien me podria compartir un codigo para hacer un buscarv en dos hojas diferentes usando macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis es:

```
Application.VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, column_index, range_lookup)
```

o

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, column_index, range_lookup)
```

funciona de la misma manera que cuando la usas en las celdas, te apso un ejemplo:
`Sub FINDSAL()

Dim E_name As String

E_name = "Juan Jones"

Sal = Application.VLookup(E_name, Sheets("NombreDeLaHoja").Range("B3:D13"), 3, False)

MsgBox "Salario: $ " & Sal

End Sub`